# Could not read excel sheet which has email and date columns in laravel maatwebsite

Tags: php, excel, laravel-4, phpexcel, maatwebsite-excel

I have a excel file which has date and email columns, date column has data something like this : **03/08/15** which is when read using laravel excel gives output as **3-Aug-15 1:00:00**. Also email field is not getting read, output is getting NULL or blank.

**But when I apply default formatting, everything getting read, but by applying default  formatting some data is getting modified which I can't afford.**

I just want to read all the excel sheet as it is without any loss in data. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've tried with PHPExel but facing same problem, help me.

Comment: Actually problem is with **OpenDocument Spreadsheet (.ods)**. If you save your data in .ods format, one could not able to read some data or data is getting modified.